# Mix Match Using Wolftooth Tanpan

Tags: derailleur-rear, customization

My current setup are using a full Shimano 105, medium cage GS 11-34t, crank are 50-34t. Through some digging, I want to upgrade the RD using Deore XT M8000 SGS Long, paired using wolftooth tanpan.

Based on [tanpan product specification](https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/products/tanpan), it should work with 2 chainring setup with 11-42t sprocket. But I'm not sure. Is there anyone having experience doing this? Do I need change the crank to lower setup, a 46-30t?

Comment: I am looking at doing the same thing with GRX shifters. I have the tanpan and and XT RD-M8120-SGS. Did this work for you? Also, what cassette did you go with?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Deore XT RD-M8000-SGS Long specs it should work (you are right at the limit though, but they are known to be conservative). No need to change the crank/chainrings (but you can if you want to).

Comment: yeah, based on the calculation it should be safe. probably gonna try it next week after I got the item.

Comment: If you want to check a configuration outside the specifications, it's always worth a (gentle) try from which stepping back is easily possible. If the shifting doesn't work, don't force anything.